# Pyspark : How to apply to a dataframe value another value depending on date in another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have my first dataframe `df` that contains `start_date` and value and my second dataframe `df_v` that contains only dates.

My `df`:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|      start_date   |value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-03-17 00:00:00|   35|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-05-20 00:00:00|   40|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-06-03 00:00:00|   10|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-07-01 00:00:00|   12|
+-------------------+-----+
```

my `df_v`:

```
+-------------------+
|       date        |
+-------------------+
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
|2019-04-10 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
|2019-06-14 00:00:00|   
+-------------------+
```

what I want is the new `df_v`:

```
+-------------------+-------------+
|       date        |   v_value   |
+-------------------+-------------+
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|            0|
+-------------------+-------------+
|2019-04-10 00:00:00|    (0+35) 35|
+-------------------+-------------+
|2019-06-14 00:00:00|(35+40+10) 85|
+-------------------+-------------+
```

trying to work like this:

```py
df=df.withColumn("lead",lead(F.col("start_date"),1).over(Window.orderBy("start_date")))

for r_v in df_v.rdd.collect():
    for r in df.rdd.collect():
        if (r_v.date >= r.start_date) and (r_v.date < r.lead):
            df_v = df_v.withColumn('v_value', 
            ...
```

Comment: What issues are you encountering?

Comment: @Tim I'm not getting the right values in the new dataframe df_v

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a `join` and an aggregation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum,when
#Join
joined_df = df_v.join(df,df.start_date <= df_v.date,'left')
joined_df.show() #View the joined result 
#Aggregation
joined_df \
.groupBy(joined_df.date) \
.agg(sum((when(joined_df.value.isNull(),0).otherwise(joined_df.value))).alias('val')) \
.show()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ,I'm actually a new beginner at Spark ,so I used the join with condition : the date in df_v is between start_date and final_date (final_date is the next start_date) 
and I tried to add the values if the start_date changes using lag function but still not working